# Android SQLite database is not created

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

The `SQLite database` is not created. I am playing with this for the past few hours but now i got tired a lot. I am not getting any errors or warnings in the `Log Cat`. Here is my code what I have tried so far. Help will be appreciated.

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    final static String DB_NAME = "citiesdata.db";
    final static String TABLE_NAME = "allcities";
    final static String ID = "_id";
    final static String CITY_CODE = "city_code";
    final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context cont;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        cont = context;
        Toast.makeText(cont, "constructor called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Toast.makeText(cont, "onCreate method called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + CITY_CODE + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(createTable);

//      INSERTING RECORDS IN DATABASE
        SQLiteDatabase writableDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CITY_CODE, "333");
        writableDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        writableDB.close();
        readCity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Toast.makeText(cont, "onUpgrade method called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void readCity(){
        Toast.makeText(cont, "readCity method called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Toast.makeText(cont, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CITY_CODE)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Calling the Constructor in the main UI Thread on a button click like this.

```
new MySQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this);
```

Permissions are...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please show more code from where you are initializing `MySQLiteHelper`

Comment: What is the exact problem? Does `readCity()` fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I shot the problem directly into the head. But How?

The logic of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` is that it doesn't call the `onCreate` method by only creating its object.

1. Whenever you try to access the database for retrieving or inserting data, if the database is not already created/available, it will call the `onCreate` method for the first time.
2. The `onUpgrade` method will be called if the database is available but the version is lower than the one you provide.

I created a `fillTable` method in my `MySQLiteHelper` class where I tried to access the database for the first time for writing by calling `getWritableDatabase` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper`. The definition of the `fillTable` method looks like this.

```
public void fillTable(){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CITY_CODE, "333");
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();
    readCity();
}
```

Call the fillTable method on a new instance of the class:

```
new MySQLiteHelper(MainActivity.this).fillTable();
```

Thanks to all those who tried to help me in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    cont = context;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Toast.makeText(cont, "constructor called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Change the constructor code, then it will work...